# PHP set_include_path configuration

Tags: php, linux, debian

I got a problem with the set_include_path, I read a lot of messages on that problem but none works for me.
I'm on Debian and my root directory would be set to /home/project/

So I tried these 4 different things :

```
ini_set("include_path", '/home/project');
ini_set("include_path", '.:/home/project');
set_include_path('.:/home/project');
set_include_path('/home/project');
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'/home/project');
```

But none works... when I do echo get_include_path(); it seems good each time.

But the 4th method works perfectly with WAMP on my computer.

Error message on ALL of these :

```
Warning: include(/config/config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/project/web/www.project.com/index.php on line 3

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/config/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/home/project') in /home/project/web/www.project.com/index.php on line 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to make use of the `PATH_SEPARATOR` constant as it is done in the documentation.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

Maybe it varies on the system you're deploying your application to..

**UPDATE**:
The include path seems to be fine, but the problem is something different..

You shouldn't be including:

```
require '/config/config.php'
```

but

```
require 'config/config.php'
```

So drop the leading slash and it should work.

Comment: Could you post the error your getting when it tries to include the file? It usually prints out the include path that was used as well. Did it change?

Comment: Sorry I needed to leave work, This works but if I include a file in the same folder what happens ?

Comment: It always takes the first one in the include path.

Comment: Ah I just learned something that I didn't know... It tests all of the path in the get_include_path() from the left to the right. Good it's ok for me :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set using this: `set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'/path/');`, this don't remove existing include_path, setted by others scripts, and add default system path separator.

Answer (score 1):

The path separator may differ.

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '.',
    '/home/project',
    get_include_path()
));
```

With this you get the current include path appended to the ones you added on your own and the correct path separator for each system.